# How to un-merge Android Studio Packages

Tags: android, android-studio, package

Anytime I create a package within a package, and create classes within that sub-package prior to adding classes to the top level package, the packages always merge together.

For example I created the `social` package, and the `contact` package within. After adding a few classes to the `contact` package, **Android studio** automatically merged the two together as:

[image]

Now if I right click to create another class, it simply places it inside the `contact` package.

How can I **"un-merge"** pakcags to allow placing classes within the `social` package?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this

In Package explorer

1) Click on small(setting) icon

2) Uncheck Flatten Package and Hide empty middle packages option

see the image below

[image]

Comment: 'Hide Empty Middle Packages' is now called 'Compact Middle Packages'